# Nhibernate multiple levels hierarchy mapped as joined subclasses fails to work with base class property

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, hierarchy, joined-subclass

I have following hierarchy:

```
ClassA->ClassB->ClassC->ClassD
```

ClassB has **PropertyA**. All classes are mapped as joined subclasses with table per-class.

Mapping is parsed with no errors but I get an error when I try to run a query:

```
ICriteria crit =session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ClassB));
crit.Add(Expression.Eq("PropertyA", value));
crit.List<ClassB>();
```

Error is as follows:

> NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve
>   property: PropertyA of: ClassC

I seem to get another related error when persisting instances of ClassD but I'd rather fix this one first.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this. My mapping was not valid - I should use multiple level joined-subclass hierarchy mapping:

```
<class
 <joined-subclass
  <joined-subclass
...
```

not linear mapping with extends attribute.